# DateTime format string

Tags: c#, .net

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2011-05-04 14:33:41"); //4 may 2011
```

How do I convert this date to `"20110504 14:33:41"`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Format it like this

```
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I think you mean `"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss"`, seconds is ss not dd.